# Will bitcoind save all wallet transactions in prune mode?

Tags: bitcoind

I have bitcoind running in prune mode (last 10000MiB). Will daemon have info about all my wallet’s transactions or just those that will fit 10000MiB tail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As long as the wallet is in place before bitcoin core has a chance to
>   prune anything, it will work properly
>   [Reference Link](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1375633.0;prev_next=next)

Let me explain. Basically here is a simplified version of how bitcoind stores wallet transactions:

- *wallet.dat* contains *Private Keys | Synced upto Block | Wallet transactions*
- When new block arrives, bitcoind looks for wallet transactions in the block and adds the ones found into  *wallet.dat* and also updates *Synced upto Block* field
- In prune mode, older block data is removed, nothing happens to *wallet.dat*

So if you activate prune mode on a running node, or boot up an old bitcoin node everything should work.
However, if you import an older *wallet.dat* into already running pruned node, it has to rescan everything from *Synced upto Block* to find the transactions. This may not be possible due to missing block data